# C# xamlに「using ディレクティブまたはアセンブリ参照が不足」を追加するには

Tags: c#

◆xamlファイル（TestDialog.xaml）

```
    <Button Content="キャンセル"
            Command="{Binding CancelComamnd}" />★①
```

◆ViewModelファイル（TestDialogViewModel.cs）
　コンストラクタ

```
    this.CancelComamnd = new DelegateCommand(() =>
    {
    ★①で呼ばれる
    });
```

◆xamlファイル（TestDialog.xaml）に★②を追加

```
    <Button x:Name="hoge" Click="Button_Click"/>★②
```

◆ViewModelファイル（TestDialogViewModel.cs）に以下のメソッド追加

```
   private void Button_Click(object sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e)
   {
    var button = (System.Windows.Controls.Button)sender;
   }
```

上記を追加したところ、以下のようなエラーとなってしまいます。
「using ディレクティブまたはアセンブリ参照が不足」とあるのですが、
xamlにどのような記載を追加する必要があるのかがわかりません…。
アドバイスをいただけると助かります。

```
'TestDialog' に 'Button_Click' の定義が含まれておらず、型 'TestDialog' の最初の引数を受け付ける拡張メソッド 'Button_Click' が見つかりませんでした。
using ディレクティブまたはアセンブリ参照が不足していないことを確認してください。
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

エラーメッセージにある通りです。

`TestDialog.xaml`で使用するイベントハンドラーは`x:Class`で指定されているクラスである`TestDialog`に記述する必要があります。`TestDialogViewModel`に対しては`Binding`経由でなければアクセスできません。